# last hour(not add -1hr) data in sql

Tags: sql, getdate

I am trying to get last hour data such a that, if getdate() is returning me '2016-11-14 13:09:09.653' then i want data from '2016-11-14 11:00:00.000' to '2016-11-14 12:00:00.000' not just 12:09 to 01:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option (assuming SQL Server 2012+)

```
Select Format(DateAdd(HH,-2,GetDate()),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00')
      ,Format(DateAdd(HH,-1,GetDate()),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00')
```

Returns

```
(No column name)      (No column name)
2016-11-14 12:00:00   2016-11-14 13:00:00
```

> **EDIT Illustration No Need to Recast**

```
Declare @Table table (SomeDateTime datetime)
Insert Into @Table values 
('2016-11-14 12:15:00'),
('2016-11-14 13:30:00')

Select * 
 From  @Table
 Where SomeDateTime Between Format(DateAdd(HH,-2,GetDate()),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00') 
                        and Format(DateAdd(HH,-1,GetDate()),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00')
```

Returns

```
2016-11-14 12:15:00.000
```

Comment: As @Matt mention (and I should have), Format() has some great functionality, but poor performance.  I tend to use is for non-record level processing.

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right, no need to cast due to implicit conversation of FORMAT() to Datetime begin done because DATETIME has a higher data type precedence than VARCHAR  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx  . I just have a habit/preference of being explicit I guess :), +1 by the way I do like FORMAT it is just so easy comparatively I wish the performance was better!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM
   TableName
WHERE
   BETWEEN

    DATEADD(HOUR,DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE()) - 2,CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))

  AND

    DATEADD(HOUR,DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE()) - 1,CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```